# Can division of elements in a vector be approximated with a Jacobian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance, jacobian

As part of a larger problem, I would like to divide some elements of a vector $ \vec y $ and combine those with the original vector elements like so:

$$ \vec y = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$ \vec u = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ y_1 \\ y_2 \\ x_1/y_1 \\ x_2/y_2 \end{pmatrix} := \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ y_1 \\ y_2 \\ r_1 \\ r_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

In particular, I would like to propagate uncertainties from $ \vec y $ to $ \vec u $. Normally I would approximate the transformation from $ \vec y $ to $ \vec u $ through the Jacobian matrix:

$$ \vec u \approx \mathbf{J} \vec y $$

$$ \mathbf{J} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1/y_1 & 0 & -r_1/y_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/y_2 & 0 & -r_2/y_2 \end{pmatrix} $$

And then the covariance in $\vec y$, $\mathbf{\Sigma}_y$, would be propagated into $\vec u$:

$$ \mathbf{\Sigma}_u \approx \mathbf{J} \mathbf{\Sigma}_y \mathbf{J}^T $$

Where I would expect significant correlations between $r_i$ and $x_i, y_i$.

However, as you may notice, actually calculating $ \mathbf{J} \vec y $ will always result in $0$ for the last two elements.

Where am I going wrong? I don't see any obvious errors in my derivation, so I think one of my assumptions must be incorrect. The most logical option being that the Jacobian matrix approximation simply does not hold for this operation. If this is true, what should I do instead?

Comment: The closest rigorous way I can think of approximating a transformation $T$ by its Jacobian is $T(\vec y) \approx T(\vec 0) + J_{T}(\vec 0) \vec y$ (although  replacing  $J_{T}(\vec 0)$ with $J_{T}(\vec y)$  might still count as a valid approximation). The point is, when you're approximating something at point $\vec y$ , you're usualy approximating by the constant value at point $\vec 0$, to which you add a linear component in the argument (Jacobian applied to $\vec y$). I'm guessing your usual transformations vanish at $\vec 0$. This one, however, is ill-defined at $\vec 0$, hence the problem.

Comment: Assuming the mean value  $\bar{y}$ of your $\vec y$ is sufficiently far away from $\vec 0$, you can use $T(\vec y) \approx T(\bar{y}) + J_{T}(\bar{y}) \; (\vec y- \bar{y})$ as an approximation. This should work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never apply the Jacobian to $\vec{y}$, you apply it to a (first-order) change in $\vec{y}$.

In a covariance calculation, you take the expectation of $\Delta r \Delta r^T$, where $\Delta r=r-E(r)$.

Let $\Delta y= y-E(y)$, i.e. $y=E(y)+\Delta y$. Then the first-order approximation is  $r(y)\approx r(E(y))+J\Delta y$. Taking expectations on both sides we see that in this approximation $E(r)=r(E(y))$ and so $r\approx E(r)+J\Delta y$, i.e.  $\Delta r \approx J \Delta y$. Then, under those assumptions,

$$Cov(r,r)=E(\Delta r \Delta r^T)\approx E(J \Delta y \Delta y^T J^T)=J E(\Delta y  \Delta y^T )J^T=JCov(y,y)J^T,$$

as wanted.

There is no problem.